# Submit data-remote Rails form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm trying to submit a Rails form using AJAX and data-remote.

The submission is triggered programmatically from javascript (`$form.submit()`).
If I do it like this I receive an InvalidAuthenticityToken error.

I tried to submit the same form without javascript by simply clicking on the submit button and it worked.
It seems that the authentication token is not sent when I submit the form using Javascript.
I did some research and I tried the following options of adding the authentication token to the data being sent

- adding the following line in the Controller
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
- adding the following line inside the form_for block
  <%= f.hidden_field :authenticity_token, value: form_authenticity_token %>
- adding :authenticity_token => true to the form_for params
- setting config.action_view.embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms to true in development.rb

I tried using all the above and each of them helped me submit the form using javascript and get rid of the InvalidAuthenticityToken error, however, even though I still had the remote: true option, the request doesn't seem to be performed using AJAX since the page reloads and renders another view template.

This being said I would like to know how can I still submit the form from javascript but without getting any errors or having the page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about calling click() on the submit button instead of submit()? :)